# Laravel/Eloquent, Return Value twice from same column

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Newb alert :)

I'm trying to query my database and get a sum of all the total products purchased over two different date ranges, i.e.

Give me the total quantity purchased in the last 7 days and the last 30 days

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| SKU | Quantity | Date     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| ABC | 30       |07-23-2022|
| ABC | 40       |06-12-2022|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Basically, I want to do something like this (which I know is completely wrong):

```
$sorted= Orders::groupBy('orders.SKU')
->selectRaw('sum(orders.quantity) as ordersMinusSevenDays)
->whereBetween('dateMinusSeven', [$from, $toTime])
->selectRaw('sum(orders.quantity) as ordersMinusThirtydays)
->whereBetween('dateMinusThirty', [$from, $toTime])
->get();
```

I have no idea what to even google for this :(

Answer (score 1):

We can start by writing a raw MySQL query for this.  Then, port that over to Laravel code.

```sql
SELECT
    SKU,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
             THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS dateMinusSeven,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
             THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS dateMinusThirty
FROM orders
GROUP BY SKU;
```

The Laravel code for this might be:

```php
$sorted = Orders::groupBy('orders.SKU')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(CASE WHEN Date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS dateMinusSeven, ' .
                'SUM(CASE WHEN Date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS dateMinusThirty')
    ->get();
```